# how can I copy a directory structure from shared location to ftp

Tags: java

I need to copy a folder (which can have a directory or files) from a shared location to FTP?
If my folder which I need to copy has 2 files and 1 directory. So in FTP my folder should have a similar structure.

Thanks

Shashank

Comment: what have you tried! probably you should google it like 'ftp upload', I think it would very popular keyword.

Comment: I need to perform this all using JAVA code. I have tried various methods of FTP API like "storeFileStream" and "stroreFile". I am able to copy single files from the shared location. Trouble is copying the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [apache commons net](http://commons.apache.org/net/). It has an FTP component. However, you need to do some coding on your own (e.g. create remote directories, copy files one by one).

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I did some research and was able to finish my work